# Passing data in ajax post issue

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Scenario :**

Need to pass an object which contains a list of sub objects to the controller.

**Issue :**

I'm able to get the object's value but not the value of list of sub objects inside the object.

**Code :**

**index.cshtml**

```
function sendData() {
    var student = {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "xxx",
        Marks: [{
            Subject: "Maths",
            Mark:80
        },
        {
            Subject: "Science",
            Mark: 75
        }]
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Receive", "Home")',
        data: student,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("done");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error For details refer console log');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Receive(Student student)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
```

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Marks> Marks { get; set; }
}
public class Marks
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public decimal Mark { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

Chrome debugger shows all the data were set.

[image]

but in controller i'm not getting the value of Marks

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stringify the data, and set the `contentType` and `type` ajax options (note that it needs to be a POST, otherwise you need to generate your data in a different way using fully qualified property names with dot notation - for example `{ Id: 1, .... , 'Marks[0].Subject': 'Maths', 'Marks[0].Mark': 80, ... }`, in which case its your existing ajax code will work without modification)

```
var student = {
    ....
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Receive", "Home")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ student: student }, // stringify
    type: 'POST', // add
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //add
    success: function (data) {
        alert("done");
    },
    ....
});
```

Note that you method is returning a view, but you not doing anything with that view. If your intention is to update the DOM with that view, then the method should be `return PartialView( ... );` and in the ajax success callback,

```
success: function (data) {
    $(someElement).html(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. Works perfectly. Just curious, Why it was not working in GET method?

Comment: Because a GET call has no body and the the values come from the query string (or route values) and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot match up the data your sending (look at the url you were generating to understand).

Comment: But it would work if the data was formatted as per the comment in the first paragraph - i.e the names are in the same format that you would use to access the value of a property in your c# code.

Comment: When you do an ajax POST, the data is sent in the body, and by setting the `contentType` option, the `DefaultModelBinder` reads that from the request header, and therefore uses the `JsonValueProviderFactory` class to deserialize your data

Comment: Thanks again @Stephen.