# how to pass serialize data and stringified data together in ajax

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a ajax function where i am passing two objects:
1) serialize form data object
2) complex object

Ajax function:

```
  var temp = sessionStorage.getItem('book');
        var viewName = $.parseJSON(temp);


        var ViewModel = $("#OffsetBookForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "Post",             
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/CreateOrder")",           
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'OffsetCommonObj': ViewModel, 'obj': viewName }),
            dataType: 'json',

           success: function (data) {

           }
         });
```

And My ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder(EstimationOffsetViewModel OffsetCommonObj, 
                                   OffsetCostCalculation obj)
        {
          // do something here..
        }
```

My problem is, the first object in action method i.e-"OffsetCommonObj" is getting null. What am I doing wrong in the code? Please Help..Thanks.

Comment: Short answer - You cannot.

Comment: then what is the alternative?

Comment: Combine them as serialized data using [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) - `data: ViewModel + '&' $.param(viewName)` and remove the `contentType` option

Comment: when i try to do like this(without contentType), 2nd object getting null

Comment: I have no idea what your models are or what data your sending and if they match!

Comment: check this link,my 2nd object is like this and it was also getting null but when i used this link approach it fixed...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432961/passing-data-in-ajax-post-issue     and i got stuck in the first object now